# Get database from crashed iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I develop an iOS app and I send it to any beta tester. After 2 month app has a crash and now it doesn't work .
I need to get any information about log or better I need database. How can I get it ? I can connect to my Mac, but I don't know how to access to db data (if is it possible).
It's very important get database information.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the Xcode organizer.

Comment: Yep, attach to a development box and use Xcode's Organizer window to pull off the app's files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your device, you can access support directories only for applications compiled for development.

Connect your device to your computer. Having launched xcode, open 'Organizer' window (Window->Organizer). On the left hand side of the menu you will have your device displayed. Under your device, select 'Applications'. All the dev applications will be available there. Select the application you are interested in and click 'Download' at the bottom of the window. What happens - the support directories are downloaded. They are stored in bundle with extension '.xcappdata'. 'ctrl' click on the file and menu will give you an option 'Show Package Contents'. You will find there your sql database file.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use XCode Organizer to download the application directory from the device, or if the tester is remote ask them to install a program like iExplore that lets you simply copy application directories off of the device to send to you.